# react router v6 isActive not updating styles

Tags: reactjs, react-router

After upgrading to react router v6 there is an issue updating the style of a `NavLink` when it is active.

The code looks like this:

```
{siteLinks.map({ href, name }) => {
  return (
    <NavLink
      key={href}
      to={href}
      style={({ isActive }) => ({
        backgroundColor: isActive ? 'gray' : 'transparent',
     })}
    >
       <p>{name}</p>
   </NavLink>
}
```

When I inspect the elements I see that the `a` tag has the `active` classname but the `style` doesn't get picked up.

If I change to the following they all show as `gray`

```
<NavLink
   key={href}
   to={href}
   style={{ backgroundColor: 'gray' }}
>
```

Comment: it wasn't working as  I was using styled-components and using `const NavLink = styled(_NavLink)`

Comment: react-router doesn't update window.location so you need to check to update it. you can try `reload={true}` prop

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try with a className

```
className={({ isActive }) =>
                      isActive  
                        ? someClass
                        : someOtherClass
                    }
```

Comment: if I'm using tailwind how would I add? isActive  ? 'font-bold' : 'font-underlined'?